# Why doesn't join() turn my list into a string?

Tags: python, list

Hey I was just wondering why in this piece of code:

```
def change_letter(line, what_letter_to_replace, what_to_replace_with):
    """
    This function takes 3 parameters: a string, the letter that is going to be  
    replaced,
    and what it is going to be replaced with.
    """
    lst_line = list(line)
    for letter in lst_line:
        if letter == str(what_letter_to_replace):
            lst_line[lst_line.index(letter)] = str(what_to_replace_with)
    x = ''.join(lst_line)
    y= x.split()
    return y
```

The function works as intended and returns a list of the words that are in the new updated line whereas in this piece of code:

```
def change_letter(line, what_letter_to_replace, what_to_replace_with):
    """
    This function takes 3 parameters: a string, the letter that is going to be 
    replaced,
    and what it is going to be replaced with.
    """
    lst_line = list(line)
    for letter in lst_line:
        if letter == str(what_letter_to_replace):
            lst_line[lst_line.index(letter)] = str(what_to_replace_with)
    ''.join(lst_line)
    lst_line.split()
    return lst_line
```

The function has a run-time AttributeError that says that 'list' object has no attribute 'split', but wouldn't the code have already made the lst_line into a string already due to the previous line?

Comment: `''.join(lst_line)` creates a string that joins the list, then throws it away. Also, I swear someone asked this yesterday. (Plus your title makes no sense; you don't have a single class or method in your code anywhere...)

Answer (score 3):

`''.join(lst_line)` does not affect `lst_line`.  It returns a *new* string.  If you want that new string to be called `lst_line`, you need to assign it back to that variable:

```
lst_line = ''.join(lst_line)
```

Notice that this is what the first example does (it just calls it `x` instead of `lst_line`).